# react-query useMutation onError never firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query, mutation

I'm currently trying out react-query in my project.

I'm having trouble with handling errors within my mutation.

In my networks tab, I can confirm that the server is responding with code 400 or 500, which I assumed makes axios throw an error, thus firing the defined onError function.

However, the onSuccess function is always called no matter how the API call goes.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

```
const { mutate } = useMutation(
['mutation'],
() => axios.patch(API_URL, params),
{
  onSuccess: () => {
    //this is always fired, even when response code is 400, 500, etc.
    void queryClient.invalidateQueries('query');
  },
  onError: () => {
    //should do something but never fired
  },
}
```

);

Comment: your code looks right, and unless you have some axios interceptors somewhere, this should work. can you reproduce this in codesandbox?

Comment: Did u solve this problem? I have same problem btw ://

Comment: props to @TkDodo, this was exactly the reason. I had forgotten that I set up an axios interceptor.

Comment: @mymoto did you get the issue? I am facing the same.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. In my case I have onError defined before onSuccess and mine seems to be executing the onError behaviour AND the onSuccess behaviour. I can't work out why

Comment: Having had a chance to properly look at my bug that I thought was similar to this it turned out I had specified the same success behaviour elsewhere earlier. So in my case the correct success and error behaviours were executing at the correct time. Sorry I couldn't help answer this one

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to return the result of your mutation function (i.e. the `axios.patch` call needs to be returned)

```
const { mutate } = useMutation(['mutation'], () => return axios.patch(API_URL, params),
{
  onSuccess: () => {
    //this is always fired, even when response code is 400, 500, etc.
    void queryClient.invalidateQueries('query');
  },
  onError: () => {
    //should do something but never fired
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Until the error comes to the mutation, some promises might interfere with it. Example:

```
.catch((error) => {
   resolve(error.response) // Must be reject(error.response)
})
```

`catch` pipe should be removed or coded to reject the promise.

Any `try-catch` block, interceptors might handle the error. In that case, the error is not returned to the mutation.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem, I searched for the solution for days.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to manage the status code in the `onSuccess` callback.
It's a bug in the `useMutation` which I am also facing so I manage the status code in conditionals. But it should work not work in case of `500`. There is a
flaw in your implementation then.

Answer (score -7):

It might be because you're passing arguments in worng order.
In docs it says you should call it as follows:

```
useMutation(mutationFn, {
   mutationKey,
   onError,
   onMutate,
   onSettled,
   onSuccess,
   retry,
   retryDelay,
   useErrorBoundary,
   meta,
 });
```

Which makes your code as follows:

```
useMutation(
() => axios.patch(API_URL, params),
{
  mutationKey: 'mutation',
  onSuccess: () => {
    //this is always fired, even when response code is 400, 500, etc.
    void queryClient.invalidateQueries('query');
  },
  onError: () => {
    //should do something but never fired
  },
}
```

Comment: The order of keys doesn't matter with objects.

Comment: Object keys order doesn't matter